# How we select date from date picker using javascript in protractor tool? can you suggest solutions?

Tags: javascript, date, select, datepicker, protractor

I have write code for select date from date picker in protractor.But this code not working.Unable to select date

```
 var tbl = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='content-wrapper']/div/div/div/div  /div[1]/div/form/div[4]/div/p/div/ul"));
var rows=tbl.element(by.tagName("tr"));

var columns=rows.element(by.tagName("td"));

  for(var i=0;i<columns.length;i++)


  {
    var st=columns.get(i).getText();
     if(st.toEqual("13")){ 
     columns.get(i).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    }
 console.log(st);
 browser.sleep(3000);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

All lines of code you placed are promises, so you first need to resolve each of them before you can use the result. For example, `columns.get(i).getText()` is a Promise, you first need to do the following before you can use the value

```
columns.get(i).getText()
    .then(function(tdText){
        console.log('tdText = ',tdText);
    });
```

You can also use a filter method on all the `td`'s like this, see the [Protractor documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
// Get all the columns in a table, this will resolve in a ElementArrayFinder
// The filter will loop over each element in the ElementArrayFinder
$$('table td').filter(function(elem, index) {
  // For each found td, get the text
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    // when a match is found, return it, else go to the next element
    return text === '13';
  });
// If an element is found based on the text it will return an ElementArrayFinder
// with 1 result, get the first element and for example click on it
}).first().click();
```

Hope this helps